# Awk command to perform division of 2 columns and gets results higher than a value

Tags: linux, unix, awk, text-processing

I have a bunch of files, each with 13 columns, I think they are tab spaced, but I am not sure and don't know how to check, because I only have access through a VPN that doesn't let me download the files. I want to divide the 13th column by the 4th and only keep the results higher than 0.6.
I tried the following command, but it only does the print part.

```
for file in *.join; do echo $file; awk '{cov = $13/$4}{cov>0.6}{print $1, $2, $3}' $file >> ../VFDB_RESULTS_FILTERED/$file.filtered; done
```

Comment: Change `{cov>0.6}` to `cov>0.6` so it's a condition rather  than an action and then let us know if you still have a problem. You should also copy/paste your whole script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the shell errors it tells you about.

Comment: The shellcheck only change the $file to be inside double quotes, but the command still doesn't divide the columns.                                                                                                                                     
 ``` for file in *.join; do echo "$file"; awk '{cov = $13/$4}cov>0.6{print $1, $2, $3}' "$file" >> ../VFDB_RESULTS_FILTERED/"$file".filtered; done ```

Comment: If you did what I said then your script will `divide the 13th column by the 4th and only keep the results higher than 0.6` exactly as you said you wanted, assuming your input is white-space separated fields with no empty fields. Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] that includes you updated script and concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert all into one `awk` script.

```
$ awk '{print FILENAME; close(f); f="../VFDB_RESULTS_FILTERED/" FILENAME ".filtered"}
       $13/$4>0.6 {print $1, $2, $3 > f}' *.join
```

perhaps guard for division by zero.

Comment: yes I just want the filenames as output .